# run python script on apache

Tags: python, apache

Hello I have an apache script: (now only for testing)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
name = form.getvalue('name')
var  = form.getvalue('var')


print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (name, var)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

and index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<form action="/cgi-bin/test.py" method="post">
nazov suboru: <input type="text" name="name">  <br />
premenna: <input type="text" name="var" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

When i add something to the frm and click submit it gives me error..
Test script helloworld works fine.. any idea where the problem is ?
I am using linux, apache and cgi-mod.

ERROR:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Comment: did you look in your `/var/logs` to see what error message was logged?

Comment: this can be so many things, it can be a formatting issue, apache virtualhost config error or it simple could be a permission issue, you need to look at the logs from apache, the web server, for instance error_log or however you configured your logs to output to which ever file. and whats an apache script?

Comment: [Fri Dec 19 22:08:33.628857 2014] [cgid:error] [pid 22087:tid 139684921149312] (2)No such file or directory: AH01241: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.py' failed




























[Fri Dec 19 22:08:33.629405 2014] [cgid:error] [pid 17380:tid 139684642498304] [client 127.0.0.1:52580] End of script output before headers: test.py, referer: http://localhost/

Comment: So, that error is telling you clearly what is wrong. Is that really where your script is?

Comment: Yes it is in cgi-bin..
(/usr/lib/cgi-bin/)